Prove that every two lines in space are equal or disjoint or interact at one point only
The question: Let $V$ be a Vactor space over $\mathbb{F}$, Let $\overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{w} \in V  : \overrightarrow{v} \neq 0 $ . Then we define
$$L_{w,v}=\{\overrightarrow{w}+\overrightarrow{v}t : t\in\mathbb{\mathbb{F}}\}$$
This is called the line passing through $\overrightarrow{w}$ in the direction of $\overrightarrow{v}$.
Prove that :
Every two lines in the space are equal or disjoint or interact with each other at one point only.
This post didn't help me understand what it means or a way to solve it, I started by saying :
Let $L_{w_{1}v_{1}}$$L_{w_{2}v_{2}}$ be lines in the  given space, then we get that if $w_2=w_1$ and $v_1$ and $v_2$ not linearly independent then the two lines pass through the same point but in different direction therefore they interact at one point only, but I don't know how to prove that or how to get the other cases

The common points of two lines $w+tv$ and $a+sb$ are determined by the solution(s) of $w+tv=a+sb$. How many possible solutions for $(t,s)$ are there?

You should study the proposed solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971735/understanding-of-the-line-passing-through-u-in-the-direction-of-v?noredirect=1&lq=1 (it's very good) and create your own example in $\mathbb R^3$ or in $\mathbb R^4$ ($\mathbb F\doteq\mathbb R$)

@StéphaneJaouen so I would get a pattern?

"Two points determine a line" is all you need.

@GerryMyerson thanks, it turns out its easier than i have imagined , i was thinking of vectors and planes and linear independace and not point.

Let me encourage you to write up a solution, and to post it as an answer.

@GerryMyerson i will and you can check it if you want.

Suggested Answer by me :
We divide the question into cases :
$L_1=w_1+v_1t_1$
$L_2=w_2+v_2t_2$
CASE $1$ :
If the lines go through the same vector $(w_1=w_2)$ and in the same direction that is $(t_1v_1=t_2v_2)$, then the lines are equal.
CASE $2$: If the lines go through the same vector $(w_1=w_2)$ and in a different direction $(t_1v_1 \neq t_2v_2)$ we get that the lines interact at one point only.
CASE $3$: If the lines go through different vectors $(w_1 \neq w_2)$ but in the same direction $(t_1v_1=t_2v_2)$ then we have that the lines never interact with each other.
CASE $4$: If the lines go through different vectors $(w_1 \neq w_2)$ but in a different direction $(t_1v_1 \neq t_2v_2)$ we have that the lines interact at one point only.
Hence we covered every case possible.

$t_1v_1=t_2v_2$ doesn't make much sense, since $t_1$ and $t_2$ have to take on all the elements of $F$. Also, lines that go through different vectors but with $v_1=v_2$ could be equal, and lines that go through different vectors with $v_1\ne v_2$ could be "skew" and not intersect at all. I think you're working too hard with all the algebra, just think of the geometry; think, for example, of why two lines can't intersect at exactly two points.

@GerryMyerson now i am not sure if is $t_1$ $t_2$ or just $t$ for both of the lines , that would change the answer , yes ?

You can use $t$ for both, but note that if there's a point of intersection, the $t$-value could be different for the two lines.
